# jquery validation plugin inline

Tags: jquery

I have

`<input type="text" class="required" ... />`

Is it possible for me to write inside class i required the particular field to number only

I tried

`<input type="text" class="number" ... />` and `<input type="text" class="{required:true, number:true}" ... />`

Is it possible and any idea how? Thanks

Comment: The `class` attribute should consist of space separated tokens (see [HTML standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/global-attributes.html#classes))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `class="required number"`, see jQuery example [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation#source), or run [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3d9y9/):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="application/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#test-form").validate();
            // don't really process form
            $("#test-form").submit(function() { return false; });
        });​

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="test-form" action="" >
            <input type="text" class="required number" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

​

Also, see my comment.

Comment: very very sorry my friend, there was an error previously on form, that why its not working.. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a mask for the input text?

See: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/